# how to delete files downloaded in command terminal?

Tags: delete

I downloaded some files like adobe reader,etc by using commands but these files are not compatible to my Ubuntu version.My question is where the downloaded file exists.....
please answer this question.

Comment: Please post the commands you used.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you downloaded with your browser so Chrome and Firefox are set to download to Downloads/ by default f.e. /home/Downloads 
If you downloaded with `wget` than either you specified location or downloaded to your current location (which you can check with `pwd`)


You can always use

```
locate <filename>
```

to find it's location, for example:

```
locate imeni
/home/<your username>/skripte/imenik
/home/<your username>/skripte/imenik/imenik
```

than just delete it with:

```
rm -f /home/<your username>/skripte/imenik/imenik
```

Comment: yeah i downloaded it with Firefox.

Comment: @Nd Prasad than do rm -f /home/<your username>/Downloads/<filename> use `tab` key to navigate